# Adding element from for loop to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I want to create an array with the values from 0 to 4000 by increments of 100 and add those to an array.

I don't have much of as to how to do it.

```
  int wave[] = {};
  for(int i = 0; i < 4000; i = i + 100){
    //add to wave[] i
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Search for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#error wrong compiler` `#endif` --- `{}` is invalid C initialization

Comment: @pmg maybe yo thought `#ifndef`?

Comment: @ tilz0r: the question is tagged C. I assume OP does not want C++.

Comment: gnu C accepts `{}` initializers (unless -pedantic is set)

Comment: @Jean: I didn't know that. I always use `-pedantic`. Anyway, if the OP wants C it doesn't hurt to include the 3 lines in my comment.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre GNU C won't accept this if size is empty!

Comment: Assume it is 4000 then, I will modify that later

Comment: @mch of course he can: `0, 100, 200, ..., 3800, 3900, 4000`.

Comment: I didn't think this would cause confusion. I've modified the thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can use C++, the default option for storing an array of integers is `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> wave;
for (int i = 0; i <= 4000; i += 100)
    wave.push_back(i);
```

If you want to have a C array as the result (e.g. for compatibility with other code that uses such arrays), because you know the final size of your array in advance, you better mention the size in the array definition:

```
int wave[41];
int index = 0;
for (int value = 0; value <= 4000; value += 100)
    wave[index++] = value;
```

If you didn't know the final size, and for some reason didn't want to use `std::vector`, you'd have to use dynamically-allocated arrays (with `malloc` or `new[]`).

Comment: Since the amount of elements is known beforehand `std::vector<int> wave(4095 / 100 + 1);` would be the more efficient way of doing things.

Comment: It should rather be `.reserve(4095 / 100 + 1)`, not initializing the `vector` with zeros (because I want to use `push_back`). I'd rather not complicate the answer with such efficiency things though.

Comment: The question is tagged as [tag:arduino]. Usage of `std::vector` or dynamic memory allocation is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
  int wave[4096/100 + 1];
  for(int i = 0, j=0; i < 4096; i = i + 100, j++)
    wave[j]= i;
}
```

Comment: `wave[4096/100 + 1]` will do the job then.

Comment: @JorgeBellón `4096/100` will be done on compile time! So there is no diff in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but again, an issue when converting from void* to int* on  `wave = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*wave)* (4096/100+1)); `

Comment: @JorgeBellón and even even if the divisionn is done at compile time, it won't make any difference, because alone the call to `malloc` is 100 times slower that the division.

Comment: @Pete `wave = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*wave)* (4096/100+1))` will compile with both C and C++ compilers.

Comment: @Pete Fixed it. It looked like pure C-code, but now I saw that you wanted help with C++.

Comment: @Pete And now I realized I should not use malloc at all in C++ :)

Comment: The question is tagged as [tag:arduino]. Usage of dynamic memory allocation is not a good solution.